# jQuery mobile loads only body content

Tags: jquery, mobile, load

When I change page in my jQuery mobile app, it never loads the header content (all scripts included). I tried to add all the scripts on the first page too but it doesn't work.

Is there a function in jQuery mobile where I can reload all includes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears you are using the one html file page architecture. 
jQuery Mobile loads the head only of the first page. When you navigate 
it makes ajax calls to load only the div that you marked with data-page attribute.
If you want to load some script you can either put it in the data-page div, or disable
ajax navigation (check [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/ajax-nav/) because there is a number of different things you can do).
If you want just to load a script that is specific for the page you navigate just put it
in the data-page div. But if you want to load same scripts disable ajax altogether (if you want it for all the pages) or for the particular page use rel external.